# How to nterface multiple records on execution of a Proxy service

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

We have a data service in DSS which is fetching records from two tables exists in our on premise sql server database, both the tables are linked and one 1 parent and second is child, i.e. 1 parent record may have multiple child records

Initially we restrict Data service to fetch only one parent record which has two childs, the data service is fetching in a right way by using call mediator and we are able to submit those records to our web service by using a call mediator which is accepting a parent and 2 child records (obviously we have a data mapping in between these two call mediators)

Now the issue is when we remove the restriction of fetching 1 parent record from data service, the data service is fetching bulk of records (parents & childs). when i invoke my proxy service it only interfaced the last record out of 100 records, our requirement is that it should interfaced all 100 records

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your goal correctly. If you want to fetch parents with their children, you can use call-query in DSS. First, in the wizard you should make the query for the children of a parent. Then you make the query for parents and in the outer mapping, you choose query, select the children query and map the parent param(s). You should not have any issues getting as many parents as you want with their children this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested queries for solve this scenario. Please follow this link https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS310/Defining+Nested+Queries